# Using Cron and Pgrep to restart a service spawns many pgrep processes

Tags: linux, cron, grep

We have a cluster of Linux PCs to grab process variables. Due to security reasons, we cannot connect them to the internet or use outside scripts/programs.
The system is supposed to start a process we'll call "serviceA" and all the arguments and necessary stuff that's important to start this process is in a .sh file

I used crontab in this way:

```
*/5 * * * * pgrep ServiceA > dev/null || /etc/PATH1/PATH2/startMiddleware.sh
```

To check if the process is running, and if not execute the bash script...

Now to the problem: I did this on friday and after the weekend I connected to the terminals of the 3 industrial PCs I activated this in, all three of them had at least 40 `pgrep` processes running when running `top` and they are slow as hell. I deleted the line out of crontab and rebooted.

I'm not a pro with Linux so please try to stay on a base level - what did I do wrong and how can I make this better?

Comment: did you mean `/dev/null` ? (note the leading `/` char). IMHO, it's never a good idea to `>/dev/null` on a new project, no telling what interesting, valuable information is being thrown away. AND to really make that complete, you would have needed `> /dev/null 2>&1` anyway. I'd go in the opposite direction with `...> /tmp/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H\%M.middlewarechecker.log) 2>&1`, but then you have to manage 12*24 per day log files, so this is only temporary too. For debugging, now you have an accurate picture of what your system is doing. You can then fix things and reduce the amt of logs.GoodLck

Comment: And of course, using `cron` to manage services has been overtaken by systemd and  its automatic systems for doing just this. There have been several good threads here on S.O. about how to accomplish this, but I only have experience reading about systemd, not really using it. Good luck.

Comment: thank you @shellter, your first suggestion solved my issues, I don't quite understand the solution as I don't know the syntax (I'm an automation engineer, not versed in Linux at all) but it does keep restarting my service and it does not junk up the process list with pgrep processes.

Comment: "automation engineer", then `bash` and `linux` should be your friend! ... In *nix, the default design is the have programs print their ouput to what is called standard out, which can be easily redirected to files via the `> /path/to/file` or into other programs with `...| grep "2nd target"` (for instance, in both cases). The missing `/` in your redirection (`>` is one of several redirection operators) indicated to start at the root of file system. Missing that it means look in the current directory for a file/directory name `dev`. `/dev` is a well know dir structure inside of *nix land.

Comment: To see what I mean, run the cmd `find /dev/ -print` to see all the stuff your version of *nix manages for your. Contrast that with `cd ; pwd; find dev -print`. Got to go, See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls , and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps to get a big leg up on using *nix scripting with bash specific features included. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use the bash program to check several programs:
check.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PROGRAM='/bin/bash'
SERVICE='chrome.sh'
FOLDER='/home/user'
 
if ps aux | grep $SERVICE | grep -v 'grep' > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running, Restarting Service $SERVICE"
    sleep 2s
    $PROGRAM $FOLDER/$SERVICE
fi
```

1. PROGRAM -> if you want to run the program when it stops
2. SERVICE -> The program that you will check
3. FOLDER -> file folder that you will run if the program stops

and I use crontab every 1 minute to run check.sh:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/check.sh >/home/user/checkDebug.log 2>&1
```

Thanks :)